# How do I combine an existing NuGet package for a CL with a Roslyn analyzer?

Tags: c#, nuget, nuget-package, code-analysis, roslyn

[Information already exists](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/magazine/mt573715.aspx) on how to create a roslyn analyzer as a NuGet package and add a new Class Library to it.

My situation is the other way around: I have a Class Library with a .nuspec attached to it that's integrated with TFS and has a whole publishing infrastructure setup around it. Changing all this to work with the analyzer's .nuspec instead would be quite a hassle.

Can I add the analyzer to the existing NuGet package?

Answer (score 4):

Yes you can!

1. Open your existing solution
2. Add a new project from the "Analyzer With Code Fix (NuGet + VSIX)" template
3. In your existing nuget project, add a normal reference to the analyzer's class library
4. Copy the `tools\` folder to the root of the existing nuget project (including the `.ps1` files)
5. Add these two lines to the existing .nuspec file:

```
<file src="$outdir$MyOrganisation.MyService.Analyzers.dll" target="analyzers\dotnet\cs" exclude="**\Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.*; **\System.Collections.Immutable.*;**\System.Reflection.Metadata.*; **\System.Composition.*" />
<file src="tools\*.ps1" target="tools\" />
```

You newly generated .nupkg will now have your analyzer included with it and add it to whichever project adds a reference to it.

For cleaning purposes, you might want to remove the Diagnostic.nuspec in your analyzer project as well as the AfterBuild event in the .csproj file.

Note: you can probably remove the `exclude` since you're now targetting a specific file whereas previously it used a wildcard to select all `.dll` files. I haven't tried it without it yet so I'll leave it in the answer for now.